# Authorization in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

The readonly users have only read permissions. Thus, a user having readonly true is not authorized to add new user or any write capabilities.

I am building a utility which manages the data in MongoDB. When i log in as readonly user it should not allow me to add new user. When I implement it, it does not actually add a user but it is not throwing any exception.

Here is my commands for adding a readonly user

```
var credentials = new MongoCredentials(username, password,false);
var addUser = new MongoUser(credentials, readOnly);
var database = server.GetDatabase(databaseName);
database.AddUser(addUser);
```

Comment: Can you paste the commands that you used to create read only user and command you used to create new users

Comment: yaaa sure.. var credentials = new MongoCredentials(username, password,false);
                    var addUser = new MongoUser(credentials, readOnly);
                    var database = server.GetDatabase(databaseName);
                    database.AddUser(addUser);

Comment: I have to explicitly check the read only users. Or is there any method to do it in mongo c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you start mongod with the --auth command line argument?

Did you use `safe=true` on your connection string?

Also, you need to use admin credentials to add a user to a database:

```
var adminCredentials = new MongoCredentials("adminuser", "adminpassword", true);
var userCredentials = new MongoCredentials("username", "password");
var user = new MongoUser(userCredentials, true);
var fooDatabase = server.GetDatabase("foo", adminCredentials);
fooDatabase.AddUser(user);
```

Notice that there are two sets of credentials: one for the user being added, and another set of admin credentials for your code to be able to add the user.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the same . On doing the same , I am getting safemodeException. But I want to ask that only specifying safe=true in connection string is only required or I have to use SafeModeResult instance to hold the result of the operation

Comment: If you want SafeMode to be on you have to choose that explicitly. The easiest way is to use safe=true on the connection string. Any operation that returns a SafeModeResult will return null if SafeMode is not on.